# alternative to if..else for determining which file to call

Tags: javascript

Im trying to find the cleanest way to chose and call a method from a given file determined by a variable. The conditions to keep in mind are:

A user will call a db and the db will return one of 10 different variables.

There will be a specific file for each variable.

Each file will have 5 methods inside, all named the same through out the different files, but making a call to a different api.

I thought about doing something like

```
import tomato = require('./vars/tomato')
import apple = require('./vars/apple')
import pear = require('./vars/pear')

fruit = (SELECT fruit WHERE name = user_input)

fruitInfo = fruit.getNutritionalInfo()
```

This how ever doesn't work as expected(although im not surprised). Is there anyway to handle this other than an `if..else` or a `switch` statement. The more concise the better.

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand you have to dynamically choose a module to call based on the result of your query. You can do it for example like this:

```
const modules = {
    tomato: require('./vars/tomato'),
    apple: require('./vars/apple'),
    pear: require('./vars/pear'),
};

const fruit = (SELECT fruit WHERE name = user_input);

const fruitInfo = modules[fruit].getNutritionalInfo();
```

which basically creates a map of modules and then you call a specific module using the `fruit` value.

Another way to achieve this is to simply dynamically `require` modules based on the `fruit` value:

```
const fruit = (SELECT fruit WHERE name = user_input);
const module = require('./vars/' + fruit);
const fruitInfo = module.getNutritionalInfo();
```